# Design approaches when separating web api from mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-6.0

net core mvc web application, it also has web api controllers layer. Since these controllers now also need to be used from another application we are thinking about separating API and exposing it independently.

I would like to understand how best to do it, what will be the different options with it specially considering authentication/authorization? Do I need to implement Identity Server or it is a nice to have?